# Do logical operators short-circuit in Rust?

Tags: rust

Do `&&` and `||` stop evaluating as soon as a result is known?
In other words will `(true == true) || (true == false)` not evaluate the right side because the whole expression is known to be `true` after only evaluating the left side.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes.

From the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#lazy-boolean-operators):

```
fn main() {
    let x = false || true; // true
    let y = false && panic!(); // false, doesn't evaluate `panic!()`
}
```

Comment: These operators also have non-short-circuiting variants `|` and `&`.