# Does collapsing a nested if using && as suggested by Clippy change the behavior?

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

I am just starting using rust and discovered the clippy assistant. I am generally very satisfied with its functionalities, but i encountered a recommendation which I do not know if I should follow.
while working with a HashMap, I want to test if a stored value (say a f32) respects a condition (say it is greater than 10.). Also, I am not sure that the value is am looking for using its key is already in the HashMap. I wrote:

```
if mymap.contains_key(k) {
    if *mymap.get(k).unwrap() > 10. {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then clippy politely asks me to collapse this if statement into one:

```
help: collapse nested if block
  |
3 |     if mymap.contains_key(k) && *mymap.get(k).unwrap() > 10. {
4 |         // do something
5 |     }
  |
```

I feel that collapsing this would bring a chance of `*mymap.get(k).unwrap() > 10.` being evaluated before  `mymap.contains_key(k)`. If so, and if the key is not already in `mymap`, this would generate an error.

I suppose there exists more elegant ways to do what I am trying to do with combinations of `if let` or so, but if I wanted to keep my `if`s, would it be possible to collapse them, and in which order would the conditions be evaluated ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644809/do-logical-operators-short-circuit-in-rust

Comment: In addition to Gereon's comment, also note that you could eliminate double lookup with `if mymap.get(k).map(|&v| v > 10.).unwrap_or(false) { /* do something */ }`. (Or `if let Some(&v) = mymap.get(k) { if v > 10. { /* do something */ } }`, but then you get to `if`s again.)

Comment: @Gereon Thank you for the link, it does answer my question. To sum up, only the left part of `mymap.contains_key(k) && *mymap.get(k).unwrap() > 10.` would be evaluated if the key did not belong to the HashMap, therefore not generating any error.

Comment: You can check and get together rather than performing double lookup: `if let Some(value) = mymap.get(k) { if value > 10 { … } }`. This one isn't collapsible (yet).